# How to create rounded corner layout from its rounded corner image background?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-drawable

I'm trying to make a custom dialog with its parent layout having a background rounded corner image drawable.

[image: theory]

This image's corners are transparent, the problem now is when I use this as my parent's background, it will still leave a rectangular corners. If you look closely on the 2nd image having still rectangular corners (black):

[image: reality]

I have applied drawable XMLs to make the parent layout's corner rounded but still with the 2nd image.

Here's my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/parent_frame"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/parent_frame"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/parent_frame"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/parent_frame"
    android:background="@drawable/red" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_x"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_x"
        android:onClick="closePopup"
        android:translationX="-10dp"
        android:translationY="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_x"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="HEHEHEHEHE"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set it to ur custom dialog -- dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));this will solve ur problem.

Comment: Please note that while Pratik is right, the view bounds will still exceed those of the background (so if you have content that fills to the edge it might go over the edge).

Comment: I initiated the dialog in my onCreateDialog by this: `AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);` In this case, what is `dialog`, is it `dialogbuilder`?